# What are the additional features available in Core Activiti 6, and Activiti 7 with respect to Activiti 5

Tags: microservices, workflow, alfresco, activiti, orchestration

We are currently using core Activiti 5.22.0.5 version for orchestration of spring-boot microservices, and now there is a requirement to upgrade Activiti to latest version of Activiti which is Activiti 7.x

Can someone please let me know what are the additional features available in latest version and also let me know if we can directly upgrade it to latest version or not?

If not possible then what should be our up-gradation flow?

(Example: Activiti 5.22.0.5 -> Activiti 6.x -> Activiti 7.x or anything else)

Please help me if anyone have worked on any similar requirement?
If not then At list let me know the difference between these versions and features available in latest versions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the release notes https://www.activiti.org/readme and migration guide https://www.activiti.org/migration ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm surprised no-one picked up the ball on this question.
Activiti 5 was superseded by Activiti 6 and has basically the same architecture with a new and improved user interface. Activiti 6 also introduced a form editor if I remember as well as basic decision (DMN) support.
Development on Activiti 6 pretty much froze when the core team moved to Flowable. Development continued at Flowable and has gone on to include some rearchitecting of the entity (persistence) model, the event model, improvements in DMN support, some seperating of components and better Spring support. There are other changes but I think this is the majority. Flowable is a very active project and if you want to maintain an on premise "Activiti" project I would recommend you move to Flowable (or Camunda who branched at Activiti version 5 and maintain a similar Architecture).

Activiti 7 was a complete rewrite specifically for cloud deployments.
Activiti 7 is architected as a set of microservices (12 factor application) that implement each of the functions (event manager, Rest interface, notification, identity management, runtime server, log server). Components are "wired" together using zookeeper as a set of individual modules that can be independently deployed.

If you are running Activiti 5 on premise, I'm not sure Activiti 7 is a good fit.
Also, the Activiti 7 project development appears to have slowed significantly recently.

For you, I would look at either Flowable (closest to Activiti 5) or Camunda.

Comment: The first time view the intro of Activiti 7, it seems a cloud based product and the system become really huge.